# creating a drawable from sd card to set as a background in android

Tags: android, image, layout, background, sd-card

I am trying to use an image from the sd card and set it as the background for a relativelayout.  I have tried other solutions that i have found here and elsewhere but they havent seemed to work for me.  here is my code.  I have commented out other ways that i have tried and didnt work.  the only thing that worked for me was using setBackgroudnResource and using a resource from the app, but this was just to test to make sure mRoot was set up correctly.  when I have tried all the other ways, it just doesn't set anything.  Anyone know what I am doing wrong, or if there is a better way to do this?

```
        //one way i tired...
//String extDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
//Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath(extDir + "/pic.png");
//mRoot.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

//another way tried..
//Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("/sdcard/pic.png");
//mRoot.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

//last way i tried...
mRoot.setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pic.png").getAbsolutePath()));

//worked, only to verify mRoot was setup correctly and it could be changed
//mRoot.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bkg);
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You do not load a drawable from SD card but a bitmap. Here is a method to load it with the reduced sampling (quality) so the program will not complain if the image is too large. Then I guess you need to process this bitmap i.e. crop it and resize for the background.

```
         // Read bitmap from Uri
     public Bitmap readBitmap(Uri selectedImage) {
         Bitmap bm = null;
         BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
         options.inSampleSize = 2; //reduce quality 
         AssetFileDescriptor fileDescriptor =null;
         try {
             fileDescriptor = this.getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(selectedImage,"r");
         } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
         finally{
             try {
                 bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor(), null, options);
                 fileDescriptor.close();
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
         }
         return bm;
     }
```

The Uri here can be supplied from a gallery picker activity.

The image then can be saved into application resources and loaded into an imageView

```
        private void saveBackground(Bitmap Background) {
        String strBackgroundFilename = "background_custom.jpg";
        try {
            Background.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, openFileOutput(strBackgroundFilename, MODE_PRIVATE));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(DEBUG_TAG, "Background compression and save failed.", e);
        }

        Uri imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo = Uri.fromFile(new File(BackgroundSettings.this.getFilesDir(), strBackgroundFilename));

        // Load this image
        Bitmap bitmapImage = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageUriToSaveCameraImageTo.getPath());
        Drawable bgrImage = new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);

        //show it in a view
        ImageView backgroundView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.BackgroundImageView);
        backgroundView.setImageURI(null); 
        backgroundView.setImageDrawable(bgrImage);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the response.so i tried it ur way and its still not working.so i use the gallery picker and grab the uri from the image, then i call your function and try to set the returned bitmap to a drawable and it doesnt work. when i check it with the getbounds, it returns 0 for left, right, top, and bottom. any idea on what im doing wrong?  here is the code i just described:Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();   Bitmap testimage = readBitmap(selectedImage);
  BitmapDrawable bmd2 = new BitmapDrawable(Multimedia.this.getResources(), testimage);
  Rect t2 = bmd2.getBounds();

Comment: The testimage is in the memory and not saved in the application's resources yet, which you may need to do in order to keep it. So to get a drawable this should do: bmd2 = new BitmapDrawable(testimage); Try with a small image first. The proper way is to pass this bitmap to a method which would scale it for the background and save before converting it to a drawable. At each stage check what are you getting using logs or Toast. Try this after readBitmap int h = bitmap.getHeight(); int w = bitmap.getWidth(); and show h and w to see the size. This method works, I tried it on many devices...

Comment: ok, so i check the bitmap height and width and i get values.  how do I save it to the applications resources or does the bitmapdrawable do that and it just needs more time to process?

Comment: I have edited my post. I think you should have now all the code to grab an image save it and use it in the application.

Answer (score 5):

```
File file = new File( url.getAbsolutePath(), imageUrl);

                if (file.exists()) {

                    mDrawable = Drawable.createFromPath(file.getAbsolutePath());

                }
```

Comment: This returns a smaller image than is stored on disk. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest checking that the drawable is being loaded correctly.  Some things to try:

- Try using a different image on the sd card
- Put pic.png in R.drawable and make sure mRoot.setBackgroundResource() does what you expect
- After loading the drawable, check d.getBounds() to make sure it is what you expect

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried what u said and the image works fine when its in the app as a resource, but when I try to get it from my sdcard ( with the check you suggested) I get a null pointer exception. Im assuming its not making the drawable, but I don't know why

Comment: It's too bad that createFromPath() doesn't throw any exceptions if the file isn't found, or is somehow undecipherable.  I'd double check that the file is there "adb shell ls -l /sdcard/pic.png". Anyone else have a suggestion?

Comment: Well I did it using a bitmap like I explained in the comment to the other answer but its not working yet and am getting all bounds are 0. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking that its not finding the file.  Double check that it's where you think it is, with "adb shell ls -l /sdcard/pic.png"