# Dynamically changing the background image after download

Tags: java, android, image-loading

**1)** I have a android application which has a default background Image()

**2)** I have a login page where the user selects an item from a drop down list ..and depending on the item i make an API call to download an image.

**3)** Once the Image is downloaded i want to change the background of that page and also cache it so as to use the same image in rest of the pages

Can anyone suggest a way to do this.
AM stuck on finding a solution since hours

Please help!!

Comment: Have you started yet? Do you have any code? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: no !!still figuring out a strategy for this.
I new at this..so sorry if i sound silly

Comment: possible duplicate of [creating a drawable from sd card to set as a background in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4770258/creating-a-drawable-from-sd-card-to-set-as-a-background-in-android)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1) I have a android application which has a default background Image()

Good start

> 2) I have a login page where the user selects an item from a drop down
>   list ..and depending on the item i make an API call to download an
>   image

Use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to download the image in `doInBackground()`

> 3) Once the Image is downloaded i want to change the background of that page and also cache it so as to use the same image in rest of the pages

You can update the background in `onPostExecute()` of your `AsyncTask`. Save the image in a DB or maybe just to a file on the device or as a `static` variable in a Global class (not recommended by most)

I hope this can help you get started